# Ksh dollar and carriage return in a string

Tags: sed, ksh, carriage-return, dollar-sign

I have a ksh script, which I have problem in insert few lines with carriage into a file.

```
#!/bin/ksh
FILE_NAME="/tmp/t.xml"
LINE="<moid>ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,Subrack=MAIN,Slot=3,PlugInUnit=1</moid>"
COUNTER_VALUE=`grep -A4 $LINE $FILE_NAME | sed -e '/-/,\$d' | grep '<r>`

sed   "1i$COUNTER_VALUE" $FILE_NAME
```

Ksh debug log asb below.

```
aaa[678] /tmp$ ksh -x ./t.ksh
+ FILE_NAME=/tmp/t.xml
+ LINE='<moid>ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,Subrack=MAIN,Slot=3,PlugInUnit=1</moid>'
+ grep -A4 '<moid>ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,Subrack=MAIN,Slot=3,PlugInUnit=1</moid>' /tmp/t.xml
+ grep '<r>'
+ sed -e '/-/,$d'
+ COUNTER_VALUE=$'<r></r>\n<r></r>'
+ sed $'1i<r></r>\n<r></r>' /tmp/t.xml
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown command: `<'
```

My question is what is the first Dollar symbol in the variable COUNTER_VALUE.
I actually want to have COUNTER_VALUE as below.

```
COUNTER_VALUE='<r></r>\n<r></r>'
```

which keep carriage return and do not have annoying dollar symbol.
This special dollar create problem in my sed command.

Please help.

Contents of file t.xml as below.

```
<gp>900</gp>
<mt>pmSwitchIngressDiscards</mt>
<mt>pmSwitchIngressLoad</mt>
<mv>
<moid>ManagedElement=1,Equipment=1,Subrack=MAIN,Slot=3,PlugInUnit=1</moid>
<r></r>
<r></r>
</mv>
<mv>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` in `COUNTER_VALUE=$'<r></r>\n<r></r>'` is not actually there.

That's `-x` showing you that the `\n` in that string is a **literal** newline and not the two characters `\` and `n`.

That embedded newline is the problem. With it there sed sees `1i<r></r>` as one command and then `<r></r>` as a second command.

You need to remove and/or escape that newline to make this work.

You can escape it with:

```
COUNTER=${COUNTER//$'\n'/$'\\\n'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However if I add one line COUNTER_VALUE='<r></r>\n<r></r>'. It works. Why?

Comment: Because your line there **doesn't** use the `$''` ANSI C quoting to make that `\n` a *literal* newline instead of two characters. If you use `COUNTER_VALUE=$'<r></r>\n<r></r>'` manually you'll get the same effect as the script.

Comment: Ok, I need the carriage return. What is the best way to escape this `\n`?

Comment: Like I said if you need that newline in the inserted contents you need to escape it with a backslash `\\`.

Comment: Sorry, I know I need to escape the new line. However, I am not able to change source file, How should I do it?